# Assigning a contact Email address to String

Tags: contact, string

I have the following error for this code "Illegal assignment from Contact to String "

system.debug gives me email address, but its giving me error when I want to insert that value into that custom field inside the opportunity

```
List<Contact> allContacts = [Select Email From Contact where AccountId=: account.id Limit 1];
      for (Contact currentContact : allContacts) {
        System.debug('Current Contact Email' +  currentContact);
        Opportunity.Email_1__c = currentContact.toString();
                      }

      System.debug('contat' + allContacts);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the `Email` field of `Contact` that you queried:

```
Opportunity.Email_1__c = currentContact.Email;
```

You can see a string version of an `SObject` such as `Contact` but that shows the names and values of all the populated fields rather than the single field value you require.

**PS**

To find out what is going on for your "empty field problem":

```
System.debug('contact Email ' + currentContact.Email);
Opportunity.Email_1__c = currentContact.Email;
System.debug('opp Email ' + Opportunity.Email_1__c);
```

Comment: Oh yah, The ID was in the system.debug too, you are absolute right. Thank you

Comment: its not adding it to the field right now, do I need to make anything like .add();?

Comment: @bez Just assigning it is correct.

Comment: hmmm it gives me an empty field

Comment: system debug gives met he correct information , its just not assigning it

Comment: @bez Weird. See the PS.

Comment: I fixed it, i was doing this after Insert. its working fine now. Thank you for your help. I didnt think I needed to insert the results of this